# htaccess not redirecting and displaying 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Im wondering if someone could help me out.

I have setup a 301 redirect from my .com.au to my com using htaccess which wordpress generated.

The homepage works fine except now everytime I try to navigate around my website I keep getting 404 errors

My htaccess is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Did it work before you added the 301 redirect? And are all pages but the homepage getting 404?

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes and Yes :)

Comment: Well the first rule shouldn't cause a redirect unless you go to .au domain. So it should just go to the wordpress rules.  So what happens if you comment out the first rule?

Comment: @PanamaJack Do you mean the RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com\.au$ [OR] line ?

Comment: No the entire block before Begin Wordpress

Comment: @PanamaJack - It seems to work fine, so it must be something wrong with the redirect rule?

Comment: Yeah, something is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your rules this way. I also made a few changes to the first redirect rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.website.com/ [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```